# How to prevent files from being stolen by editing html code?

Tags: html, css, security, web, flask

I have a simple Flask app that lets you download an image protected by a login. There are simply two routes:

```
example.com/login
example.com/downloadpage
```

You can't access "downloadpage" before you have successfully logged in. That's working fine. The folder structure looks like the following:

```
--flaskapp.py
----static
------images
--------background.png
--------protectedimage.png
------stylesheet.css
```

The login page looks like this:

```
< body style="background:url('../static/images/background.png');">
    <!--Login-->
</body>
```

If you now go to `example.com/login` and change the source code in the browser by clicking inspect in Chrome for example you can easily change `'../static/images/background.png'` to `'../static/images/protectedimage.png'` the protected images will be set as background and you can easily save it. How can you prevent users from being able to do that? Of course I want them to be able to download the protected image by clicking the download button on `example.com/downloadpage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly through HTML, CSS, JS or PHP their is no solution for your problem.

You could set a .htaccess file to access the page instead of PHP. 
An easier solution is maybe to copy the file into a folder with a complicated name, something like the SESSION ID and set the path via PHP to SESSION ID/protectedimg.png

And if the SESSION is destroyed just delete the folder again.

Answer (score 2):

Images/CSS/JS files are resources that can be protected in a similar manner to regular Flask views.

Don't store and serve resources from under the `static` folder, instead store resources in a private location (Flask instance_paths could be used) and create routes that serves resources using `send_file`.

The routes need to check if the `current_user` is authenticated and authorised (use roles for this). The routes also need to disable browser caching of the resource.

A simple example (`@nocache` is a decorator that sets an appropriate response header):

```
@app.route('/resource/image/<string:filename>')
@nocache
def resource_image(filename):

    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return '', 204

    _image_path = get_instance_path('images', filename)

    if not op.isfile(_image_path):
        print "Image not found : {}".format(_image_path)
        return '', 204

    print "Serving image : {}".format(_image_path)

    return send_file(_image_path)
```

The route would be used in a HTML template as follows:

```
<p>This is an unprotected page with a protected resource (image). If you are logged in you will see an image below.</p>
<img src="{{ url_for('resource_image', filename='black.jpg') }}">

<div style="padding:20px; height: 560px; width: 760px;background:url('{{ url_for('resource_image', filename='background.png') }}')">
    <p>If you are logged in you will see this paragraph is in a <code>div</code> that has a protected <code>background:url</code></p>
</div>
```

Full working example using Flask, Flask-Security and Flask-Alchemy on Github - https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-protected-resource

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other poster that there is no solution to your problem in the way that you're hoping for.

I would add, however, that you could obfuscate the filenames (like this, for example: `kjhsdfh978y3h4i2uhdllupyu878366jsf.jpg`) of your protected images so it would be almost impossibly hard for people to guess the filename in dev tools.

It's worth nothing that this still won't make the files impossible to find but it's an easy fix that would deter almost anyone.

Comment: Thank you. You are saying not in the way I am hoping for but what is a good way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Using a database would be a way to secure those images unless the user is authorised

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is **no** way to stop people from viewing your source code and ultimately changing it though there are some ways you can deter those pesky users.

[Here's the link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm) from where the relevant content has been copied.

> **Source Code Padding**
>
> Really, the oldest trick in the book. It involves adding a ton of
>   white space before the start of your code so that the view source menu
>   appears blank. However, must all people will notice the scroll bars
>   and will scroll around to find your code. As pointless and silly as
>   this method is, there are some still who use it.
>
> **No Right Click Scripts**
>
> These scripts stop users from right-clicking, where the "View Source"
>   function is located. Cons: Notoriously hard to get working across
>   browsers and to actually work properly. The right-click menu, or
>   context menu, includes many helpful tools for users, including
>   navigation buttons and the "Bookmark Page" button. Most users don't
>   take kindly to having their browser functionality disabled and are
>   inclined not to revisit such pages. The View Source function is also
>   available through the top Menu. At the main menu bar at the top of
>   your browser, select View, and then in the sub-menu, you'll see "View
>   Source" or something similar. Also, there are keyboard shortcuts like
>   Ctrl+U that can be used to view source. All this method does is add
>   about a two second delay to someone trying to view your source and it
>   does irritate users who aren't trying to view your source.
>
> **"JavaScript Encryption"**
>
> This is by far the most popular way to try to hide one's source code.
>   It involves taking your code, using a custom made function to
>   "encrypt" it somehow, and then putting it in an HTML file along with a
>   function that will decrypt it for the browser. A User is able to view
>   the source, however, it isn't understandable. Cons: Your website is
>   only usable for users with JavaScript enabled. This rules out search
>   engines, users who've chosen to disable JavaScript, and users using a
>   textual browser (such as the blind) that doesn't have JavaScript
>   capabilities. Remember, JavaScript is a luxury, not a necessity on the
>   web. You have to include a means of decrypting the page so the browser
>   can display it. Someone who understands JavaScript can easily decrypt
>   the page. Many browsers provide alternative ways around this. Some
>   allow you to save the page, decrypted for easy viewing later. Others,
>   like FireFox, include tools like the DOM Inspector, which allows you
>   to easily view and copy the XML of the page, decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

For ctrl keyboards:

Try the shortcuts.js libary (http://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js) or the code:

```
    shortcut={'all_shortcuts':{},'add':function(shortcut_combination,callback,opt){var default_options={'type':'keydown','propagate':false,'disable_in_input':false,'target':document,'keycode':false}
if(!opt)opt=default_options;else{for(var dfo in default_options){if(typeof opt[dfo]=='undefined')opt[dfo]=default_options[dfo];}}
var ele=opt.target
if(typeof opt.target=='string')ele=document.getElementById(opt.target);var ths=this;shortcut_combination=shortcut_combination.toLowerCase();var func=function(e){e=e||window.event;if(opt['disable_in_input']){var element;if(e.target)element=e.target;else if(e.srcElement)element=e.srcElement;if(element.nodeType==3)element=element.parentNode;if(element.tagName=='INPUT'||element.tagName=='TEXTAREA')return;}
if(e.keyCode)code=e.keyCode;else if(e.which)code=e.which;var character=String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase();if(code==188)character=",";if(code==190)character=".";var keys=shortcut_combination.split("+");var kp=0;var shift_nums={"`":"~","1":"!","2":"@","3":"#","4":"$","5":"%","6":"^","7":"&","8":"*","9":"(","0":")","-":"_","=":"+",";":":","'":"\"",",":"","/":"?","\\":"|"}
var special_keys={'esc':27,'escape':27,'tab':9,'space':32,'return':13,'enter':13,'backspace':8,'scrolllock':145,'scroll_lock':145,'scroll':145,'capslock':20,'caps_lock':20,'caps':20,'numlock':144,'num_lock':144,'num':144,'pause':19,'break':19,'insert':45,'home':36,'delete':46,'end':35,'pageup':33,'page_up':33,'pu':33,'pagedown':34,'page_down':34,'pd':34,'left':37,'up':38,'right':39,'down':40,'f1':112,'f2':113,'f3':114,'f4':115,'f5':116,'f6':117,'f7':118,'f8':119,'f9':120,'f10':121,'f11':122,'f12':123}
var modifiers={shift:{wanted:false,pressed:false},ctrl:{wanted:false,pressed:false},alt:{wanted:false,pressed:false},meta:{wanted:false,pressed:false}};if(e.ctrlKey)modifiers.ctrl.pressed=true;if(e.shiftKey)modifiers.shift.pressed=true;if(e.altKey)modifiers.alt.pressed=true;if(e.metaKey)modifiers.meta.pressed=true;for(var i=0;k=keys[i],i1){if(special_keys[k]==code)kp++;}else if(opt['keycode']){if(opt['keycode']==code)kp++;}else{if(character==k)kp++;else{if(shift_nums[character]&&e.shiftKey){character=shift_nums[character];if(character==k)kp++;}}}}
if(kp==keys.length&&modifiers.ctrl.pressed==modifiers.ctrl.wanted&&modifiers.shift.pressed==modifiers.shift.wanted&&modifiers.alt.pressed==modifiers.alt.wanted&&modifiers.meta.pressed==modifiers.meta.wanted){callback(e);if(!opt['propagate']){e.cancelBubble=true;e.returnValue=false;if(e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}
return false;}}}
this.all_shortcuts[shortcut_combination]={'callback':func,'target':ele,'event':opt['type']};if(ele.addEventListener)ele.addEventListener(opt['type'],func,false);else if(ele.attachEvent)ele.attachEvent('on'+opt['type'],func);else ele['on'+opt['type']]=func;},'remove':function(shortcut_combination){shortcut_combination=shortcut_combination.toLowerCase();var binding=this.all_shortcuts[shortcut_combination];delete(this.all_shortcuts[shortcut_combination])
if(!binding)return;var type=binding['event'];var ele=binding['target'];var callback=binding['callback'];if(ele.detachEvent)ele.detachEvent('on'+type,callback);else if(ele.removeEventListener)ele.removeEventListener(type,callback,false);else ele['on'+type]=false;}}
```

And to call the ctrl+U use this code, I altered the ctrl u to redirect in New tab to a different page with source I wanted to display! So use something like:

```
<script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js"> < /script>
<script>

shortcut.add("Ctrl+U",function() { 

         window.open('view-source:https://antimalwareprogram.co/pages.php', '_blank').document.location = "https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js";
  });
</script>
```

Or leave no script to disable it
And add this example code to use a new one:

```
<script>

shortcut.add("Ctrl+J",function() { 

         //your code here
});
</script>
```